# storing user input into an array and referring to the array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

This code works properly well but it doesn't have a memory for storing user input.

I also need to categorize the grades into its respective columns in array format, having "S/N, Category and Count" and I dont know how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
namespace ExamScore
{    
    class YourExamScore
    {    
        private static string GetGrade(int examScore)
        {
            if (examScore >= 90 && examScore <= 100)
                return "Excellent";

            if (examScore >= 70 && examScore <= 89)
                return "Good";

            if (examScore >= 50 && examScore <= 69)
                return "Satisfactory";

            if (examScore >= 0 && examScore <= 49)
                return "Unsatisfactory";

            return "Invalid";    
        }    

        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            // Print a greeting message.  After all, why not?
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to ExamScore Calculator!");

            Console.WriteLine("Input Your Exam Score...");
            Console.WriteLine("Press -2 when you have inputed all scores");
            while (true)
            {
                var examScore = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (examScore == -2)
                {
                    break;
                }

                var grade = GetGrade(examScore);
                Console.WriteLine(grade);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nProccessing Scores... Please Wait...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }          
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please add a `homework` tag.

Comment: No its not a home work, i work for this new firm but undergoing c# training cos i'll be needing it a lot these days

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like a homework, so i am not going to help with codes directly,

for the storage of marks, you can follow either of one way

1. if you know how many input you are going to use, then use a fixed size `array`

   var marks = new int[10];
2. if the no. of input is not fixed then you can use `List<int>`

   var marks = new List();

Comment: its not a home work, even though its dealing with student work, but i appreciate your response. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly, but I think you are asking to keep track of the amount of grades that fall in a certain category. In that case, I would do it as follows.

You will need to keep track of an array of ints (`int[]`) with an entry for each category that keeps track of the amount of grades in that category so far. So you will first have to make a static array of size 4, which will automatically initialize with zeroes everywhere. Semantically, each index stands for a category (say 0 for excellent, 1 for good, etc.). Then, in the `GetGrade` method you should for each category also increase the right category before returning.

Comment: S/N   Category   Count
1      Excellent   5
2     Satisfactory  8
etc  this format is what i was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

To store user input in memory you can use array or list (`List<MyData>` is better if you have to insert often, `Hashtable` if you want to search fast, `MyData[]` - least memory and fastest access by index, etc.)

After entering `-2` you may want to store (serialize) your data somehow, so data will persists between runs. It can be xml-file (`XmlSerializer`), own format text-/binary- file, database, etc.

You also need to define how you will work with data: are they saved immediately after entering (then database itself is a memory storage) or upon exit, delete/correct possibility and such.

Finally, you can add statistic and reporting, which *query* your data and produce results.

It is a bit unclear what

> "S/N, Category and Count"

stands for. Could you elaborate? Your code is asking for `score` and producing `grade`. You could count how many users have which grade, how many total users, how many grades (all those are "Counts"), but "S/N" and "Category" are confusing.

---

To example, you only want to print how many users belongs different grades.

1) Very manual approach, count occurrences (statistic) upon entering (use)

```
int grade90plus; // fields
int grade70plus;
...
    // inside GetGrade
    if(examScore > 90)
    {
        grade90plus++;
        return "Excellent";
    }
    else
        if(examScore > 70)
        {
            grade70plus++;
            return "Good";
        } 
...
// report
Console.WriteLine("Excellent: " + grade90plus);
Console.WriteLine("Good: " + grade90plus);
```

2) [High tec](http://dotnetfiddle.net/e9yYhY) (serialization unfriendly)

```
public class Grade
{
    public string Name;
    public int Count;
    public int ScoreMin;
    public int ScoreMax;

    public bool Test(int score) { return score >= ScoreMin && score <= ScoreMax; }

    public static readonly Grade Excellent = new Grade() {Name = "Excellent", ScoreMin = 90, ScoreMax = 100};
    public static readonly Grade Good = new Grade() {Name = "Good", ScoreMin = 70, ScoreMax = 89};

    public static readonly Grade[] GetAll = new Grade[] { Excellent, Good };
}   

private static string GetGrade(int examScore)
{
    foreach(var grade in Grade.GetAll)
        if(grade.Test)
        {
            grade.Count++;
            return grade.Name;
        }
    return "Invalid";
}

// report
foreach(var grade in Grade.GetAll)
    Console.WriteLine(grade.Name + "," + grade.Count);
```

You can surely improve those or make own solution (serialization friendly, utilizing database, one what uses expressions for `Test`, etc).

Comment: S/N   Category   Count
1      Excellent   5
2     Satisfactory  8
etc  this format is what i was trying to achieve

Comment: Still doesn't completely fit. You know what `S/N` stands for *serial number*? =D

Comment: Yes Serial Number is supposed to be another column in the array for clarity purpose, while arranging category and count in a 2-dimensional array, but i can leave it out if you feel its not useful

Comment: hi Sinatr...i don't know how to send a direct message to you so i had to come back here. Do you know the best way to convert a console application to a Web form? the search results i got on here dint explain much about it. Thanks for your time